# Facebook SDK for Unity: How to set app version when logging app events to be displayed in App Insights?

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-insights, facebook-unity-sdk

**Facebook SDK for Unity** provides methods for logging app events: [`FB.AppEvents.LogEvent`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/fb.appevents.logevent). I've tried to log `ActivatedApp` using this line of code:

```
FB.AppEvents.LogEvent(Facebook.FBAppEventName.ActivatedApp);
```

The event was logged to my Facebook's App Insight but no app version specified as displayed:

[image]

I'm looking for a method to set app version for app event logs of **Facebook SDK for Unity** that equivalent to `[FBSettings setAppVersion:]` method of **Facebook SDK for iOS**.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook SDK Settings in Unity can be accessed from the Menu Bar->Facebook->Edit Settings, but it does seem that App Version can not be configured in the current version of the SDK.